# R, vector of strings to vector of inputs

Tags: r, shiny

TL;DR:

I have this vector/list of characters, it could either look like this:

```
list_of_inputs <- c('input$thing_1', 'input$thing_2', ...)
```

or like this:

```
list_of_inputs <- c('thing_1', 'thing_2', ...)
```

What I need is to convert it so it is interpreted like this:

```
c(input$thing_1, input$thing_2, ...)
```

Is this possible?

---

The reason is I want to programatically make shiny inputs, and programatically check when one of them has been hit. If I manually declare inputs in ui.R/ui-function, this works:

```
observeEvent(c(input$manually_made_1, input$manually_made_2), {
    print('a button has been hit!')
}
```

And this also works:

```
observeEvent(c(input[['manually_made_1']], input[['manually_made_2']]), {
    print('a button has been hit!')
}
```

I can't just give observeEvent the list_of_inputs as a vector/list of strings/characters, as it doesn't understand that. But if I try to make a list using a loop:

```
input_list <- c()
for(i in 1:length(list_of_inputs){
    input_list <- append(input_list, input[[paste0('thing_',i)]])
}
```

input_list ends up containing nothing but NULL (or several)...
I tried using as.symbol() but that didn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `sapply(list('thing_1', 'thing_2', ...), function(x) input[[x]])`

Comment: @HubertL Worked perfectly in the observeEvent, thanks. Seems like you can't assign it to a variable but that doesn't really matter. Wanna make an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution for your consideration. The Shiny app below takes a list of lists of button information (id, label, and callback) and adds an `actionButton` and observer for each item. Each button press will trigger the corresponding callback function from the list.

The call to `local()` is key. If the call to `local` is removed only the final expression of the for loop is registered as an observer. Credit for the `local` workaround goes to this thread https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/ and Winston Chang.

If multiple buttons need to share a callback you can define the function outside of the list and reference it multiple times. If there is no need for multiple callbacks you could forgo including a callback element in the lists and build out the event expression of `observeEvent` instead.

```
library(shiny)

myButtons <- list(
  list(
    id = "first",
    label = "First Button",
    callback = function() {
      print("The first button was pushed??")
    }
  ),
  list(
    id = "second",
    label = "Second Button",
    callback = function() {
      print("And now the second button was pushed")
    }
  )
)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    lapply(
      myButtons,
      function(btn) actionButton(btn$id, btn$label)
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    for (btn in myButtons) {
      local({
        btnLocal <- btn
        observeEvent(input[[btnLocal$id]], {
          btnLocal$callback()
        })
      })
    }
  }
)
```